# Why isn't the html checkbox symbol displaying properly? I'm trying to build all the elements using the dom

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to build all of my elements manually using the DOM tree, and I'm trying to add a checkbox symbol like this:

```
   //Add date
    var tdDate = document.createElement("td");
    tdDate.textContent = ("" + workoutList[idx].date);
    tr.appendChild(tdDate);
    //Add checkbox1
    var tdCheckbox1 = document.createElement("td");
    if(workoutList[idx].checkbox1 === 1){
            tdCheckbox1.textContent = (&#2713);
    }
```

To use the html code for checkbox. I get the error: `script.js:119 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token &`

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in quotes to be a valid `token(string)`

A suggested in comments, use `innerHTML`(It is HTML entity) instead of `textCOntent` as node is `textContent` will treat it as `TextNode`

```js
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = '&#x2713';
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

### [**List of HTML Entities**](http://www.danshort.com/HTMLentities/index.php?w=dingb)

Comment: That causes it to actually display as &#2713. The goal is to get it to display a checkbox.

Comment: For this to work it must be set with `innerHTML` not with `textContent` and to display the correct Symbol it needs to be `tdCheckbox1.innerHTML= '&#x2713';` note the x because it's in hex notation

Answer (score 1):

`&#2713` is HTML notation for JavaScript use `'\u2713'`